# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am having some issues with my website vertolanguages.com

I have installed ninja forms and the modal form addon and it works on some pages: http://vertolanguages.com/how-it-works/

but not on others: http://vertolanguages.com/pricing/

The error found is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

The error is on line 184 of js_composer_front.js

```
ver = jQuery.ui ? jQuery.ui.version.split('.') : '1.10',
```

Does anybody have any suggestions? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.ui.version` is undefined, your problem lies elsewhere. You can't call a function on an undefined object. A more proper way of calling this would be:

```
ver = jQuery.ui.version ? jQuery.ui.version.split('.') : '1.10',
```